# What is JsonUtility and why does my code use it?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, web-services, webmethod

I have a webmethod in a webservice where `JsonUtility.GenerateIndentedJsonText = true` is written. But I don't know why JsonUtility has been used. The code is running fine without JsonUtility..

So, what is the use of JsonUtility.GenerateIntentedText in this context?

Comment: I don't believe that is part of any .NET Framework class. You'll have to provide us with more context, like what other libraries the code uses, what are the `using` statements at the top of this file, etc..

Comment: How should we know?  We can't see your code.  We're not Psychic

Comment: I have got the answer basically it change the json object to indented json text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that your service that is using [JSON for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csjson/), which is a now inactive project for handling JSON in .NET (funnily enough). It uses the System.Net.Json namespace.

JsonUtility mostly holds a bunch of formatting related things (quotes, escaping+unescaping strings etc). The GenerateIndentedText flag simply means that any JSON generated by the library (i.e., when you use WriteTo on any JsonObjects) will be indented. Indentation doesn't affect JSON functionally, so turning it off or on doesn't really matter other than affecting human readability.